# Adding row when dropdownlist item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

[image]

I have data rows named module, priority, request date, etc which is acquired dynamically on my website. Is there a way i can add a row under module named "cost center" when the value of computer request is selected from my dropdown list? 
This is the code for the drop down list.

```
    <span id="dg_form_ctl02_lbl_show_tag" style="display:inline-block;background-    color:Transparent;border-color:Navy;border-width:3px;border-style:Double;font-    family:Arial;font-size:12px;width:130px;">Module*</span> 
                                                </td><td>








                                                    <select name="dg_form$ctl02$DropDownList1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'dg_form$ctl02$DropDownList1\',\'\')', 0)" id="dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1">
        <option value="">--select one--</option>
        <option value="Cellular Phone">Cellular Phone Request</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Computer">Computer Request (Up to VP Approval)</option>
        <option value="Account Creation">Create Network/SAP Account</option>
        <option value="Account Delete">Delete Network/SAP Account</option>
        <option value="FIS">FIS</option>
        <option value="FP">FP</option>
        <option value="General">General Support</option>
        <option value="Report">Reports</option>
        <option value="SAP">SAP</option>
        <option value="Web Application">Web Application</option>

    </select>





                                                </td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td valign="top">
```

this is the code i have so far for the alert

```
function alertMe() {
var n = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1").value;
if (n == "Computer") {
alert ('Changed');
```

Comment: Yes everything is possible only your efforts are required.

Comment: Yes, so far i have been able to display an alert (popup) for when computer request was selected. I just need a new row

Comment: can you post your relevant code, that you have tried so far.

Comment: how does your HTML markp (view source in browser) looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will work

```
selectObject.add(option,before)


function GetSelectedValue(selectItem)
{
var index = document.getElementById(selectItem).selectedIndex;

alert("value =" + document.getElementById(selectItem).value);
alert("text =" + document.getElementById(selectItem).options[index].text);
}



<select id="mySelect">
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Pear</option>
<option>Banana</option>
<option>Orange</option>
```

Comment: My data source is from sql server 08. That is where i'm pulling the data from.